# Story about enemies in a space battle sharing their last moments over com as their ships die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, warfare

I am looking for the title of a short sci-fi story which I read sometime around the mid '80s.

It is about a man and a woman talking through some communication system during the last moments of their destroyed spaceships. Before the battle they were enemies, but as their end is nigh, they start to become friends. That is all I can recall.

Comment: Are you certain that it was after a battle? If not it sounds very much like Kaleidoscope by Ray Bradbury.

Comment: I think I remember this. They're both waiting for their repair systems to fix their ships so they can fire. In the end, her ship fixes itself first and she fires on the man (?)/

Comment: I'm thinking this is by Poul Anderson but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: This sounds very familiar to me. And not just because I watched Enemy Mine a few weeks ago, either.

Comment: This is very similar to "To The War Is Gone" by IIRC Robert F Young. A musician drafted into an interstellar war against puppet-mastered humans is the last living crew of part of a ship, and will die in his gun turret as he can't reach the lifeboat section. Another part of a ship draws close, and it has an enemy crew-member aboard with a spacesuit, but no lifeboat. They talk via radio, but although they become friendly, the musician can't trust her as she may be parasitised by one of the slug-like aliens.

Comment: This sounds similar to something I read when I was buying every Baen book I could find.  Skimming through my collection, I can't find a matching story by Poul.  I read through the Fleet anthologies at the same time but I don't think it came from there.  Don't think it was an Anvil or Laumer story.

Comment: It sounds similar to a John Varley short story I read a long time ago.  If it comes to me I'll post it but it might be worth searching his stuff.

Comment: @bcsapper The John Varley story you think of is "The Black Hole Passes" from the collection ["The persistence of Vision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Vision_(collection)) The man and the woman in the stories aren't enemies, but business rivals and also lovers (as far as possible with 3D video communication as the only contact). Their outposts are massively damaged by a black hole.

Comment: There was an episode on Andromeda (tv series) that has this plot device, if it's possible you saw it rather than read it.

Comment: How sure are you that it was a man and a woman? That reminds me of the origin story for James White's Sector General, though that was human and Alien (Orligian) instead.

Comment: This scene sounds like the ending of _Limbo Search_ by Parke Godwin [link](https://www.amazon.com/Limbo-Search-Parke-Godwin/dp/0380773007/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1519744968&sr=8-1&keywords=parke+godwin+limbo+search)

Comment: I remember something similar in one of the culture books, one of the ships keeps a channel open to the other as it dies.

Comment: This sounds familiar... I am thinking its two space fighter pilots who's ships had been disabled (and were drifting very close to each other or had collided and stuck together... They were drifting in a sub orbital path around a planet, and would soon burn up when they reached the atmosphere.

Comment: This reminds me of a story where two people had to talk to each other in space for several hours straight. A man and a woman. They ended up telling each other so many secrets that they had to marry to get spousal immunity :)

Comment: I know a story like that, except it's more than one person.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, and I know this isn't what OP is looking for, but... The [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52Gg9CqhbP8) for **Let's Go** by **Stuck in the Sound** does feature a man and a (incorrectly identified) woman, a destroyed spaceship, some conflict, and becoming friends in the face of oblivion.

Comment: Sounds like Tableau, a short story by James White, and part of the Sector General series.

Comment: Son of Interflux by Gordon Korman has a short story in it that matches... Could that be it?

Comment: It's too recent, but I think there's a chapter a bit like this in Iain M Banks' *Surface Detail*. I think two(?) pilots/minds mopping up a "smatter swarm"

Comment: I went and re-read *Tableau*. I don't think it was his best writing, and the language is obviously dated—but still moving. And then I re-read most of the others!

Comment: In the small-ship standoff genre I like Saberhagen's "The Peacemaker" and "The Face of the Deep" (ok the small-ship/big-ship standoff genre)

Comment: This sounds something like the Ray Bradbury story "The Kaleidoscope" where a ship is destroyed and the people in it, all in space suits, are scattered.  The Captain has conversations with them as they drift.   The radio adaptation done for Dimension X in 1951 matches a little better in that there is a pseudo-conversation with the captain and his wife (see https://archive.org/details/Dimension-X/Dimx_e048_Kaleidoscope.mp3)

Answer (score 4):

["To the War is Gone"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54567)(1966) by Richard C. Meredith ([available on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v04n02_1966-11/page/n77/mode/2up)) as [suggested by Covert Walrus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/story-about-enemies-in-a-space-battle-sharing-their-last-moments-over-com-as-the/277545?noredirect=1#comment213100_37365) ticks a number of boxes. It was published in the November 1966 issue of *Worlds of Tomorrow*.

> Dral was a soldier. So was his enemy—it made no difference she was also a young girl!

The story opens and ends with a quote of Thomas Moore's song ["The Minstrel Boy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Minstrel_Boy).

> The Minstrel-Boy to the war is gone,
> In the ranks of death you'll find him;
> His father's sword he has girded on,
> And his wild harp slung behind him.
> "Land of song!" said the warrior-bard,
> "Tho' all the world betrays thee,
> One sword, at least, thy rights shall guard,
> One faithful harp shall praise thee!"
> Thomas Moore
> 1779-1852

It features Dral Mancil, a Cannoneer Second Class, sitting in his gun turret in the wreckage of the *Rakewind*, playing his varmel, a 8-stringed instrument. Fragments of the songs he plays are interspersed throughout the story. Dral is without a space suit, his leg broken, and no way to reach the lifeboat, when he sees an enemy soldier, a Thorna, heading for that same lifeboat from the wrecakge of *their* ship. He can't bring himself to fire, as that would destroy the already slim chance he has of using that lifeboat, so he tries to contact the soldier.

After having reached the lifeboat, the enemy soldier answers.

> "'Ello, in the cannon turret, can you 'ear me?" a feminine voice said from the loudspeaker in the console of the cannon controls.

She's called Tonu'Lehani. She tells him that while she was on the Thorna ship, she is not a Thorna herself. Thorna have an alien parasite called a "Little Brother" which allows a shared consciousness between Thorna. But according to Tonu just about 5% of the Thorna faction are actual Thorna, with a Little Brother. Tonu is in a similar predicament as Dral, because the lifeboat's fuel cells have been smashed. While coming close to killing here a couple of times, he gradually warms up to her, which sort of matches with your recollection of them becoming friends. Dral even sings her songs, playing his varmel.

Using a spacesuit from the lifeboat, she's able to rescue Dral with his varmel. But it turns out she has betrayed him, because she *does* have a Little Brother. She paralyses him and informs him a Thorna warship is on its way to pick them up, since he's the only survivor of his ship and may possess knowledge of its new shield that allowed it to go undetected. He may not have conscious knowledge, but may have overheard conversations and picked up things which he may not remember, but once fitted with a Little Brother himself, surely will. And her Little Brother is ready for fission.

But Dral is able to free himself and uses his varmel, that had been handed down through generations, to smash and kill Tonu's Little Brother, causing her to die with it. The story ends with Dral firing at the Throna warship, knowing that he too will soon die from its missiles.

> The Minstrel fell!—but the foeman's chain
> Could not bring that proud soul under;
> The harp he lov'd ne'er spoke again,
> For he tore its chords asunder;
> And said, "No chains shall sully thee,
> Thou soul of love and bravery!
> Thy songs were made for the pure and free,
> They shall never sound in slavery."
> Thomas Moore

Comment: Does not seem to have the plot aspect of them becoming friends.

Comment: @OrganicMarble well, kinda sorta. I'll edit to focus a bit more on that. But basically, Dral wants to kill the enemy soldier for a long while, then warms up to her offer of friendship and mutual aid (space suit and fuel cells), then ends up being betrayed and killing her.