# Two space-fighters have a conversation in space while waiting for their ships to fix themselves

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall an episode of a TV show, probably 1980s or 1990s, definitely in colour.

The main plot revolved around two 'one man' spaceships fighting a battle in space. Both ships are damaged and both are hanging nose-to-nose while they wait for their automatic repair systems to fix their ships. After some time, one of the protagonists, a woman, contacts the other, a man, via her ship's radio. They have an involved conversation about why they joined the military and eventually agree that they're not so different after all. They even flirt a bit, from what I can recall.

At the end, the woman's weapons come back online first but in their new spirit of friendship and mutual respect she

> **kills him**. (Ha! Bet you didn't see that coming. Well, neither did he).

---

I'm reasonably sure it's not "Outer Limits", "Welcome to Paradox" or "Masters of Science Fiction" but it was certainly in the same sort of budget range.

Comment: @zabeus - I think I know which one you mean, but I'm sure that was a prose story, not a TV show. It's probably what jogged my memory of this one.

Comment: @user14111 - I don't think so. When I saw it, I [noted the similarity](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/story-about-enemies-in-a-space-battle-sharing-their-last-moments-over-com-as-the#comment118657_37365) but the twist ending was especially memorable and I fail to see how the OP of that question would have mis-remembered something that startling.

Comment: Ah yes, and the inevitable downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an episode of Andromeda, [Una Salus Victus](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Una_Salus_Victus), though both pilots are women.

Beka Valentine in the Eureka Maru and a Nietzschean woman who can't reproduce.

> Beka runs interference, allowing the supply ship to make it to
> Slipstream, and destroying one of the Nietzschean fighters. She is
> reluctant to follow directly, because she does not want to lead the
> Nietzscheans back to the Andromeda. She opens a Slipstream portal to
> blind their sensors, reverses course, and heads straight back at them.
> She destroys the second fighter, and disables the third, but the Maru
> is crippled in the process.
>
> Beka evaluates the damage, and realizes that it will take her four
> hours work to fix either the weapons or the engines, and she knows
> that the Nietzschean pilot is also working on repairs, so she chooses
> to work on the engines. The Nietzschean pilot hails her, and Beka is
> surprised to find that it is a woman, Parvati Quechua. Quechua offers
> to let Beka surrender, since she has nothing against her personally.
> Beka says that she knows Parvati Quechua is also damaged, and offers
> to accept her surrender. She declines, and it becomes a race to make
> the necessary repairs.
>
> Parvati Quechua has finished her repairs, and hails Beka Valentine one
> last time, and asks her if she has any last messages to be conveyed.
> Beka, desperate, bypasses the life support systems to enable fire
> control, and destroys Quechua's fighter, but she regrets the
> necessity.
>
> <sub><sup>[Andromeda wiki: Una Salus Victus](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Una_Salus_Victus)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the episode name and a brief synopsis. Thank you very much. This has been bugging me for months :-)

Comment: Glad I could help!